# JavaScript & Ajax without refreshing CRUD

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, axios, page-refresh

i have a problem about **JavaScript**. i want to create CRUD without refreshing page. I can create, read and delete item. But when i update item it gives problem.
I want a function to work (I send an id to the function as data) when table tr double click is clicked or edit icon is created,
Function get data from api by ID and fill the form
First time when i submit form it update form correctly. But second time i update another item and submit it. System updates this and previous item
this process is repeated for the third time.  At this time, the data in every 3 lines changes according to the last data
This proses repeating again and again
I logged ID with alerts. And i send my kod below. Could somebody help me?

````
            const options = {
                headers: {'Authorization': "Bearer " + readCookie('AuthToken')}
            };

            let UrlArgs = {
                'action': "read",
                'module': "positions",
                'sector': "hrm"
           };
            alert(ids); //**one ID**
            urlgen(UrlArgs).then(url => { 
                axios.get(url + "/" + ids, options)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        alert(ids); //**one ID**
                        let data = response['data'];
                        $('#PositionEditModal').text("Pozisiya redaktə edilir: " + data['name']);
                          $("#PositionEditForm input[name=name]").val(data['name']);
                        $('#PositionEditForm select[name="permission_level"] option').each(function () {
                            if ($(this).val() == data['permission_level']) {
                                $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
                            }
                        });
                        alert(ids); **//one ID**

                        $('.PositionEditModal').modal('show');
                        $(document).on('click', '#submitUpdate', function () {
                           
                            let id = data['id'];
                            alert(id); //**two ID**
                            // $('#PositionEditForm input, #PositionEditForm select').jqBootstrapValidation({
                            // preventSubmit: true,
                            // submitSuccess: function ($form, event) {
                            //     event.preventDefault();
                            //     $this = $('#submitUpdate');
                            $('#submitUpdate').prop('disabled', true);
                            let form_data = $("#PositionEditForm").serialize();

                            $.ajaxSetup({
                                headers: {
                                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
                                }
                            });
                            alert(id);
                            let editUrl = "";

                            editUrl = '{{route("erp.panel.hrm.positions.update", ":id")}}';
                            editUrl = editUrl.replace(':id', id);
                            $.ajax({
                                url: editUrl,
                                method: "POST",
                                data: form_data,
                                cache: false,
                                beforeSend: function () {
                                    $(".beforeSend").hide();
                                    $(".loadingSend").show();
                                },
                                success: function () {
                                    setTimeout(function () {
                                        $('#PositionEditForm').trigger('reset');
                                        $('.PositionEditModal').modal('hide')
                                        errorManagment(null, "Vəzifə uğurla redaktə edildi");
                                    }, 1000);
                                    setTimeout(function () {
                                        datafetch();
                                    }, 1000);
                                },
                                error: function (request) {
                                    $.each(request.responseJSON.errors, function (key, item) {
                                        errorManagment(item)
                                    });
                                },
                                complete: function () {
                                    setTimeout(function () {
                                        $('#submitUpdate').prop("disabled", false);
                                        $(".loadingSend").hide();
                                        $(".beforeSend").show();
                                    }, 800);
                                }
                            });
                            data = "";
                            // },
                        })

                    }).catch(function (error) {

                    httpMessage(error.response.status).then(message => {
                        errorManagment(message);
                    });
                });
            })

        }```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assigning the click event each time you get a response from Axios. These events are appended in this case to the element with ID submitUpdate. Maybe you need to remove all existing click events for that element with the "unbind" or "off" function in jquery before assigning a new on-click event to the same element.

- unbind is deprecated in the current version of jquery, use off instead

Answer (score 0):

## Create an API.

The easiest way of doing this is creating an api. You could then dynamically update the API and send HTTP Get (or POST) requests to read the api and update the page based on that.

You can do this when any server-side language. You can create a path (like `/api/detail/get_crud`) and on the server send the data that is stored there. This is the easiest way as well as the best way of doing this.

This will also make it possible to recreate your site easily, it has a lot of upsides. I'll list a few right here:

1. Easy to remake whole site
2. Easy to use
3. You can send JSON data to the API (JSON is quite easy to use)
4. You control everything

Here are a list of cons:

1. You have to make an HTTP request constantly to update the data on the site

A lot of sites use APIs like this. Take https://repl.it for example. They have an api. Like these:

1. https://replit.com/data/profiles/(username) = display `(username)`'s **public** data
2. https://replit.com/data/repls/@(ownerofrepl)/(replname) = display `(replname)`'s **public** data.
3. https://replit.com/graphql

Also, I would use `fetch` if I were you. It's a lot easier to use.

Hope this helps! (Sorry if this doesn't answer your question, I couldn't fully understand it)